# Solving displacement of volume in water after a object is dropped inside the water container?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

> A $\pu{53.7 g}$ object having a density of $\pu{5.39 g mL-1}$ is added to a graduated cylinder containing water and sinks to the bottom. The water level is now at the $\pu{82.2 mL}$ mark. What is the volume of the graduated cylinder?

My work so far:

$$V = \frac{m}{\rho} = \frac{\pu{53.7 g}}{\pu{5.39 g mL-1}} = \pu{9.96 mL}$$

Should I just take the displacement of the water with the object sunk to the bottom to arrive at the original volume of water like so:

$$\Delta V = \pu{82.2 mL} - \pu{9.96 mL} = \pu{76.2 mL}$$

If not, what do I need to do to finish this problem?

Comment: I am a little confused by the assignments question *What is the volume of the graduated cylinder*. Are you sure, these are the words? Because to me, the volume of the cylinder does not have anything to do with its actual contents. For example: I may fill my 250 mL cylinder with only 100 mL of liquid.

Comment: This is not chemistry because it speaks about water. At least we can consider it as physics because it speaks about volume. By the way this is only math because everybody should know a liquid takes the shape of its container.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not chemistry in the slightest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**, you are correct.

You calculated the Volume of the object, which was added to the water in the cylinder to give the total volume of 82.2 mL. So deduct this and get your solution... which you did.